# How to do scroll-able and sort-able table with fixed header and first column in html

Tags: html

I dunno the html table which able do sorting and scroll-able with fixed header and first column.

Anyone can guide on this?

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/, http://www.fixedheadertable.com

Comment: ya the example on fixedheadertable.com is what exactly what i want and i read it before but i cant really understand on it if i didn't practice it..... i didn't see any example code on the fixedheadertable.com